# SQL: Query for group by and conditions with NA

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, rmysql

I want to write an SQL query calling for a column after group by two columns. I'm working on R Studio using RMySQL package. My server is MySQL.

The table looks like this.

```
organisation      ID     ZIP         Order
        Ikea     ABC     123    2018-05-30
        Ikea     ABC     123    2018-06-01
        Ikea     ABC     123    2018-06-02
        Ikea     DEF     123    2018-06-20
        Ikea     DEF     123    2018-07-01
        Ikea     DEF     123            NA
        Ikea     GHI     123    2018-06-07
        Ikea     GHI     123    2018-06-09
```

I want to group the table by `organisation`, `ID` and `ZIP`, and take groups where the earliest `Order` in the group is in June. In case of NA I want to ignore them.

So the result should look like this:

```
organisation      ID     ZIP         Order
        Ikea     DEF     123    2018-06-20
        Ikea     DEF     123    2018-07-01
        Ikea     DEF     123            NA
        Ikea     GHI     123    2018-06-07
        Ikea     GHI     123    2018-06-09
```

Here is my attempt but I'm just not sure if it's correct or not. I don't think it deals with NAs as I desire. It'd be wonderful if somebody checks/corrects this.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM MyTable t JOIN (SELECT organisation, ID, ZIP 
                     FROM MyTable WHERE organisation LIKE Ikea
                     GROUP BY organisation, ID, ZIP
                     HAVING MIN(Order) >= 2018-06-01 AND
                            MIN(Order) < 2018-07-01
                    ) tt
                    ON tt.ID = t.ID AND 
                       tt.organisation = t.organisation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is basically correct:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM MyTable t JOIN
     (SELECT organisation, ID, ZIP 
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE t.organisation = 'Ikea'
      GROUP BY organisation, ID, ZIP
      HAVING MIN(Order) >= '2018-06-01' AND
             MIN(Order) < '2018-07-01'
     ) tt
     ON tt.ID = t.ID AND 
        tt.organisation = t.organisation;
```

I added single quotes around the string and date constants.

I assume that `NA` is really represented as `NULL` in MySQL.